# For loop with .replace()

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I need to change the 'names' list to the 'username' form.

```
names = ["Joey Tribbiani", "Monica Geller", "Chandler Bing", "Phoebe Buffay"]
--> 
usernames = ["joey_tribbiani", "monica_geller", "chandler_bing", "phoebe_buffay"]
```

I wrote the code as below but it only outputs ["phoebe_buffay"]

```
names = ["Joey Tribbiani", "Monica Geller", "Chandler Bing", "Phoebe Buffay"]
usernames = []


for name in names:
    names = name.replace(" ", "_").lower()
    usernames = names
    
    
print(usernames)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: `names` is a list. Here you do `names = name.replace(" ", "_").lower()` so you have replaced your list with a single updated item

Comment: in the loop you just want one line that has `usernames.append(name.replace(" ", "_").lower())`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one line:

```
usernames = [n.replace(" ", "_").lower() for n in names]
```

The problem is that `usernames` is always replaced in the loop. Try `usernames.append(name.replace(" ", "_").lower())` instead

Comment: This solution is very effective!

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful with lists

The following code will work

```
names = ["Joey Tribbiani", "Monica Geller", "Chandler Bing", "Phoebe Buffay"]
usernames = []


for name in names:
    usernames.append(name.replace(" ", "_").lower())


print(usernames)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `name` instead of `names` and you don't have to assign a new value to `usernames`, you have to append a new item to the list instead.

##### Code

```
for name in names:
        name = name.replace(" ", "_").lower()
        usernames.append(name)
```

Comment: `usernames.append(name)` (not `names`)

Answer (score 1):

```
names = ["Joey Tribbiani", "Monica Geller", "Chandler Bing", "Phoebe Buffay"]
usernames = []
for name in names:
    usernames.append(name.replace(" ", "_").lower())
print(usernames)
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables in python are pointers to an underlying object.

### Problem

Initially you set `usernames`->`[]` and in each iteration of the for loop you set `names`->`name.replace(" ", "_").lower()`.

In the last iteration that will evaluate to `names`->`"phoebe_buffay"`.  You then update `usernames`->`names` which evaulates to `usernames`->`"phoebe_buffay"`

### Solution

Build up a new array in the for loop:

```
usernames = []
for name in names:
    usernames.append(name.replace(" ", "_").lower())
```

**Using list comprehensions**

Building up lists is exactly what python designed the list comprehension for:

```
usernames = [name.replace(" ", "_").lower() for name in names]
```

**Using the map function**

Alternatively you can use the map function to apply your 'mapping' to all elements:

```
usernames = list(map(lambda name: name.replace(" ", "_").lower(), names))
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to write usernames.append(names) in order to insert a name in the usernames array.
Like following:

```
names = ["Joey Tribbiani", "Monica Geller", "Chandler Bing", "Phoebe Buffay"]
usernames = []


for name in names:
    usernames.append(name.replace(" ", "_").lower())
    
    
print(usernames)
```

Comment: The first loop line also replaces the `names` array.